# Distributions, integral manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I do not understand the following: "Let D be a smooth distribution on M such That through each point of M there passes an integral manifold of D". I understand the distribution of M, I do not understand: *through each point of M there passes an integral manifold of D*.

thank you.

Comment: Do you know the definition of an integral manifold for the distribution? (A submanifold $N$ such that the tangent space to $N$ at every point $p\in N$ agrees with $D$ at $p$.)

Comment: A submanifold $(N,\psi)$ of $M$ is an integral manifold of distribution $D$ on $M$ if $d\psi(N_{n})=D(\psi(n))$ for each $n\in N$... but, each point of $M$ there passes an integarl manifold of $D$?? I do not understand!

Comment: OK, so you consider it with the embedding $\psi\colon N\to M$. Then the statement in italics means: *for every $p\in M$ there exists $(N,\psi)$ and $n\in N$ such that $\psi(n)=p$.*

Comment: Ok I understand ... as a vector $v\in M_{n}$... There is a curve $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(n)=p$ and $\gamma´(n)=v$ Obrigado!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll copy my comment into the answer box, so that the question does not appear unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in italics means: for every $p\in M$ there exists an integral submanifold $(N,\psi)$ and $n\in N$ such that $\psi(n)=p$.